# Integrating Instant payment Notification of PayPal in ADF

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am building a application in which I want to integrate a payment gateway of PayPal. After the payment is successfully it should update a database value.
Someone suggested for using IPN (Instant payment Notification) of PayPal.
But I could not find any work around to do this.

I can use html/jsp/jsf but not php.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Java code sample for IPN:
https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623

That should hopefully work for you.